# Flow of control? or Control of flow?

Tags: terminology, programming-languages

In most PL textbooks (even in language specifications) statments like **if, while, for, break** are categorized as *flow of control* statements. 
However, it is not consistent; i.e. sometimes the same text uses *control-flow statement* (note the dash), or *control flow statment*, I read sentences that says *control flows...*

I understand those statements *control the flow of execution*, hence *control of flow*. But many texts (even [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_of_control)) says otherwise, implying *control is something that flows in a program*

What is the formal, language-agnostic definition of this concept in CS, if any?

Comment: Please note that 'control flow' means 'flow of control', not 'control of flow'!

Comment: Too bad we don't have a native English speaker in this thread.

Comment: This is a basic law of English morphology (that applies to all Germanic languages).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you mean by "language-agnostic definition of this concept in CS"; such notions are rarely (if ever) rigorously defined. Someone uses them first, others pick them up and eventually they become standard vocabulary. That's ho we get conflicting notation all the time.

In this case, I don't see an either-or. Both makes sense, depending of how you look at it. The semantics of the language control the flow of execution, i.e. determine which statement is executed next. But as this control -- once it is implemented in a processor -- only looks at the current statement, it flows along, that is control flows.

Comment: I have a CS textbook on design of programming languages by Terrence Pratt. It mentions Sequence Control. It mentions _structured control statements_. But nowhere in that text I've seen the term control-flow or flow of control. So I'm curious where it comes from, since I have to do some explaining to students who constantly challenge and reason.

Comment: @user1728338 Well, [Google Scholar has 3.7 million hits](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=control+flow&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C39), so it certainly is a relevant notion. I have no idea who coined it, though. I seem to remember Knuth using the term, but I'd have to look this up.

Comment: I'm aware of the wide-spread usage, but it seems to me people are just following suit without giving attention. I tend to think this was initially coined as "control-flow statement" as in "push-button ignition" (_pushing of button_, therefore _controlling of flow_). Then someone somewhere forgot to put the dash and things became mixed up afterwards.

Comment: Meanings of words change all the time. There are plenty of redundant, inconsistent, and even contradicting terms in mathematics. So what are you after here? Do you want to use a word people understand, or do you think there is a "right" one, or are you just interested in the term's history?